# Taking multiple tags in XML

Tags: xml, parsing, dom, minidom

I am using XML dom minidom and I am doing the following which perfectly works. However, I want in the last line of the code I have uploaded, instead of taking only "lunch" to have also "dinner". Essentially, I want the length to be determined on how many times it gets the elements lunch AND dinner. Now it does it only for lunch as far as I understand. How can I do it?

```
sites = doc.getElementsByTagName("Employees") 

datetimeNested =  [ [sites[ i ].getElementsByTagName("Time")[ 0 ].firstChild.nodeValue] * 
                 len( sites[ i ].getElementsByTagName("lunch") ) for i in range( 0, len( sites )  ) ]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Specifically, please tag the language you are using (not just its library/module) and provide a fuller [mcve] including sample XML, issue with current result, and desired output. Thanks!

Comment: thank you, I will do so but I need help with this question

Comment: Please [edit] your question so we can help!